# Set variable into route title in Aurelia with Router

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I want to set a route parameter into my route title.

Basically, I want to make something like this:

```
configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
  config.map([
    { 
      route: ":var1", 
      name: "myName", 
      title: "my title" + " n° " + ":var1", 
      moduleId: "x/y/z" 
    }
  ]);
}
```

I want to concatenate strings with my route parameter where `var1` is my route parameter.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not when you define the router config.

But in the component itself, when it loads up, you can mutate title.

```
export class Z {
  activate(params, routeConfig) {
    routeConfig.navModel.setTitle("my title" + " n° " + params.val1);
  }
}
```